# Does the notification disappear after sometime

Tags: support, notifications, account-suspension

I had a SO account which got suspended just now (I know the reasons, And sorry for those). Now earlier I saw there was a notification from the moderator on reason of my suspension. But instead of reading it I closed the window by mistake. Now there is no notification of that message from the moderator. Do they disappear after you just click on them once?

Comment: As far as I know, such messages are also sent by email, so check your email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to [your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/2232629/akshat) -> select [inbox tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/2232629/akshat?tab=inbox). Here you will get all your inbox notifications.

Comment: Got it. Actually I did not notice that it was in inbox and not notification. Thanx..